# Golang array update doesn't work

Tags: arrays, go, struct

Hi Golang newbie coming from Java world. I have this very simple piece of program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
  A [5]int
}

func main() {
  s := make([]Foo, 0)
  var foo Foo
  s = append(s, foo)
  foo.A[0] = 42
  fmt.Printf("%v", s[0].A)
}
```

However, this prints `[0,0,0,0,0]` instead of `[42,0,0,0,0]` that I expected. After swapping the line `s = append(s, foo)` and `foo.A[0] = 42`, it does print `[42,0,0,0,0]`. Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is a slice with elements of type `Foo`. `Foo` is a struct type. Structs, when assigned to a value, passed as an argument, or appended to a slice, are copied by value. Your `append` line is adding a *copy* of `foo` to `s`, while you intended to add a *reference* to `foo`.

To fix, make `s` a slice of *pointers* to your struct:

```
s := make([]*Foo)
var foo Foo
s = append(s, &foo)
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/daXunJAn1A)

Pointers may seem scary to people who have only experienced them painfully in c. In go, they simply allow you to control if you want to copy something or pass a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks! this is a perfect answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are appending `foo` as it currently exists to `s`. This copies `foo` by value, creating a copy of `foo` appended to `s`. When you print `s`, you're printing the newly created (when it was initialized to 0) `foo` that was added to `s`, not the modified `foo` array.

When you switch `s = append(s, foo)` and `foo.A[0] = 42`, you're doing the same thing, but this time you're seeing your expected result because you're copying the `foo` array, with 42, into `s`. If you were to modify `foo` again `fmt.Printf("%v", s[0].A)` would still give you `[42,0,0,0,0]`